# Python BeautifulSoup Print Info in CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I can print the information I am pulling from a site with no problem. But when I try to place the street names in one column and the zipcodes into another column into a CSV file that is when I run into problems. All I get in the CSV is the two column names and every thing in its own column across the page. Here is my code. Also I am using Python 2.7.5 and Beautiful soup 4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2

url="http://www.conakat.com/states/ohio/cities/defiance/road_maps/"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

f = csv.writer(open("Defiance Steets1.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Name", "ZipCodes"]) # Write column headers as the first line

links = soup.find_all(['i','a'])

for link in links:
    names = link.contents[0]
    print unicode(names)

f.writerow(names)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how to get the zip code.  Also you are not using f.writerow in the loop that reads the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you retrieve from the URL contains more `a` elements than `i` elements. You must filter the `a` elements and then build pairs using the Python `zip` buildin.

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
links = [link for link in links
         if link["href"].startswith("http://www.conakat.com/map/?p=")]
zips = soup.find_all('i')

for l, z in zip(links, zips):
    f.writerow((l.contents[0], z.contents[0]))
```

Output:

```
Name,ZipCodes
1ST ST,(43512)
E 1ST ST,(43512)
W 1ST ST,(43512)
2ND ST,(43512)
E 2ND ST,(43512)
W 2ND ST,(43512)
3 RIVERS CT,(43512)
3RD ST,(43512)
E 3RD ST,(43512)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (`python3`) is to find next sibling after every `<a>` link, check if it's a tag and extract its value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 
import urllib.request as urllib2

url="http://www.conakat.com/states/ohio/cities/defiance/road_maps/"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

f = csv.writer(open("Defiance Steets1.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Name", "ZipCodes"]) # Write column headers as the first line

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    i = link.find_next_sibling('i')
    if getattr(i, 'name', None):
        a, i = link.string, i.string
        f.writerow([a, i])
```

It yields:

```
Name,ZipCodes
1ST ST,(43512)
E 1ST ST,(43512)
W 1ST ST,(43512)
2ND ST,(43512)
E 2ND ST,(43512)
W 2ND ST,(43512)
3 RIVERS CT,(43512)
3RD ST,(43512)
E 3RD ST,(43512)
W 3RD ST,(43512)
...
```

Comment: Your method works great also thank you. I have a quick question how would you remove the ( ) from around the zip codes. Thank you

Comment: @Codin: A string (`i.string`) is a iterable too, so you can use a slice to remove the first and last characters: `a, i = link.string, i.string[1:-1]`