# Getting soup contents into structured csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website and place it into a structured data format. 
I'd like to end up with a .csv with 6 columns: country, date, general_text, fiscal_text, monetary_text, fx_text.

The mapping is like this:

```
country <- h3
date <- h6
general_text <- p (h3) (the p tag that follows the h3 header)
fiscal_text  <- p (1st h5 ul li) (the p tag that follows the **first** h5. This tag is inside ul and li blocks)
monetary_text <- p (2nd h5 ul li) (the p tag that follows the **second** h5. This tag is inside ul and li blocks)
fx_text <- p (3rd h5 ul li) (the p tag that follows the **third** h5. This tag is inside ul and li blocks)
```

The pattern ends at the next h3 (country) heading.

I'm finding it difficult to get each element in its proper place/column.

The site structure repeats this for each country (see below for the actual tags):

```
h3
 p
h6
h5
 ul
  li
   p
h5
 ul
  li
   p
h5
 ul
  li
   p
```

I have the following code for simple text extraction:

```
import requests
import io
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
URL = 'https://www.imf.org/en/Topics/imf-and-covid19/Policy-Responses-to-COVID-19'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(class_='rr-intro')

with io.open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for header in results.find_all(['h3', 'h6', 'h5']):
        f.write(header.get_text() + u'\n') 
        for elem in header.next_siblings:
            if elem.name and elem.name.startswith('h'):
                # stop at next header
                break
            if elem.name and elem.find_all('p'):
                f.write(elem.get_text() + u'\n')
```

From the comments, I thought it makes sense instead to create lists and somehow zip them. I tried this:

```
h3 = results.find_all('h3')
h6 = results.find_all('h6')
h5 = results.find_all('h5')
h5f = results.find_all('h5', text='Fiscal')
h5m = results.find_all('h5', text='Monetary and macro-financial')
h5x = results.find_all('h5', text='Exchange rate and balance of payments')
country = [country.get_text() for country in h3]  #list of countries
date = [date.get_text() for date in h6]  #date string
```

I'm stuck here. Not sure how to get the contents of the p-tags to go to the right place in a list so it would be zipped, or directly to a csv.

I'm a python rookie, so I made these based on what I found on stackoverflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, The structure of what I want looks like this.

```
<div class="rr-intro">

 <h3>
  Country 1
 </h3>
 <p>
  summary text
 </p>
 <h6>
  date
 </h6>
 <h5>
  Fiscal
 </h5>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p>
    text for fiscal of country 1
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <h5>
  Monetary and macro-financial
 </h5>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p>
    text for monetary of country 1
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <h5>
  Exchange rate and balance of payments
 </h5>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p>
    text for FX of country 1
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
  <h3>
  Country 2
 </h3>
 <p>
  summary text
 </p>
 <h6>
  date
 </h6>
 <h5>
  Fiscal
 </h5>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p>
    text for fiscal of country 2
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <h5>
  Monetary and macro-financial
 </h5>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p>
    text for monetary of country 2
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <h5>
  Exchange rate and balance of payments
 </h5>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <p>
    text for FX of country 2
   </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
   <h3>
  Country 3
 </h3>
```

etc...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638900/python-beautifulsoup-print-info-in-csv) help at all?

Comment: Where does `results` come from?

Comment: @CannedScientist I understand that code but I can't wrap my head around applying it to the logic I need for the site I'm scraping. I need element h3=country, h6=date, h5=text_type. The h3 is followed by content in <p>. The h6 has not content (just the date). h5 is complicated because the <p> comes after <ul> and <li>. I don't quite see how to direct each of the contents into the right places in the .csv. I think I need to make lists or something, but it is beyond me.

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx Sorry. I was missing a line of code. It's there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the easiest approach is to deal with the elements as you read them in order. To do this you could keep track of the current section and then append text into that section.

A Python CSV `DictWriter` can be used to write a row of information once the next `h3` country is found. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.imf.org/en/Topics/imf-and-covid19/Policy-Responses-to-COVID-19'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('div', class_='rr-intro')

section_lookup = {
    'Fiscal' : 'fiscal_text',
    'Moneta' : 'monetary_text',
    'Macro-' : 'monetary_text',
    'Exchan' : 'fx_text',
}

with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f_output:
    fieldnames = ['country', 'date', 'general_text', 'fiscal_text', 'monetary_text', 'fx_text']
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()

    row = defaultdict(str)
    section = None

    for elem in results.find_all(['h3', 'h6', 'h5', 'p']):
        if elem.name == 'h3':
            if row:
                csv_output.writerow(row)
                row = defaultdict(str)

            row['country'] = elem.get_text(strip=True)
            section = "general_text"

        elif elem.name == 'h5':
            section = section_lookup[elem.get_text(strip=True)[:6]]
        elif elem.name == 'h6':
            row['date'] = elem.get_text(strip=True)[27:]
        elif elem.name == 'p' and section:
            row[section] = f"{row[section]} {elem.get_text(strip=True)}"

    if row:
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you a `data.csv` file starting:

[image: Excel screenshot showing first two rows]

Comment: This is an education for me. I had came up with another code that creates 4 different .csv files and joins them, but it had an off-by-one error due to multiple p-tags. This is much better. I'm not sure what the "row" logic is doing, but I will learn from it. Very clever use of the lookup dictionary too. I also learned something about 'section_lookup' and the [:6] logic. Very cool and much appreciated

Comment: `row` is a dictionary which holds the values for one row. I use a default dictionary to make it easier to append the p tags.

Comment: My last challenge here is dealing with some encodings. The page is UTF-8 and I know how to text and get it using Soup. It reads and displays fine. But I think when the script extracts the p-tags it loses this (e.g., sao tome and principe). The text gets garbled in the csv. I tried adding formatting code (.encode('utf-8') ) and (.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') ) to both 'csv_output.writerow(row)' and 'row = defaultdict(str)', but it gets worse. I'll dig into this problem, but I thought I should point it out if anyone uses this and runs into the same issue. Cheers!